# Why were both the sun and the moon red today?

Tags: atmosphere, moon, sun

Today was a normal day, except the sun and moon colors were strange. After 5pm, the sky was covered with cirrostratus-like translucent clouds and the sky was a blend of blue and grey.

Everything would be fine, except that the sun was orange between 4-5pm. Then by around 5-6pm, the sun was completely red like blood even though it was still high up, and it was 1+ more hour to sunset.

Then, I didn't look at the sky until 8pm when it was already dark. When I went out, the moon was red just like the sun couple hours before.

The whole thing I saw from around south side od Chicago on US Labor Day (4 Sep, 2017). I didn't take pictures of the sun unfortunately because I disregarded its color, but I took pictures of the moon.

Here's how the moon looked through my phone camera, through binoculars:
[image: Red moon 1]

Here is a similar picture but edited so that the moon looks exactly like I saw it with naked eye:
[image: Red moon 2]

**What can thia be caused by?** (As of writing this at 10:06pm the moon is still red, and it is 6 hours since both the sun and the moon were red/orange)

**EDIT: I also didn't see anything about this phenomenon in the media which is strange, and once again, this was seen from Chicago.**

Comment: I experienced the same in Germany on the 31st of August.

Comment: If you think it's bad in Chicago you should see what we woke up to in Seattle today. There's a thin layer of ash on everything.

Comment: Is it safe to look at the sun when it's in this condition? We still have our eclipse glasses but you can't see anything at all with them on.

Comment: @stannius, yes, it's as fine as it is to look at the sun normally (not very fine, but not like an eclipse)

Comment: @Eric, I live in seattle, and I left my window open last night (so hot). Woke up to ash ALL OVER my room.

Comment: Smoke from western fires.  We've had this in southern Minnesota for several days.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Smoke.  There was significant smoke across the USA, which attenuated the light from the sun/moon due to increased scattering.  The smoke particles effectively cause the light to reflect in different directions, so you see more colors.

See below for the [HMS Smoke Polygons](http://www.ospo.noaa.gov/Products/land/hms.html) for the day, which clearly shows smoke over your region from the intense smoke/wildfire activity in the Pacific Northwest.  You can also see the [NASA Worldview](https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/) composite of VIIRS visible imagery for the day, with fire locations in red.

[image: HMS]

[image]

Comment: HMS Smoke Polygons -- not the best name the Royal Navy ever chose for a warship.

Comment: It would be better to add where the smoke originated (even though many know it already).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Its in the answer: "from the intense smoke/wildfire activity in the Pacific Northwest"

Comment: @Polygnome I was searching for "LA" or "Los Angeles" haha

Comment: The smoke has been so intense here lately that many mornings you can barely see the sun, and when you can it is very very red.