# What does "red sun at night, sailor's delight" mean and is it true?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, weather-forecasting, sun

There is proverb that sounds like:

> Red sun at night, sailor’s delight; red sun in the morning, sailor
> take warning.

Is it valid and if it is then what is it about?

Comment: See [Is the old adage "Red sky at night, sailor's delight. Red sky in morning, sailor's warning" true, or is it just an old wives' tale?](https://www.loc.gov/everyday-mysteries/meteorology-climatology/item/is-the-old-adage-red-sky-at-night-sailors-delight-red-sky-in-morning-sailors-warning-true-or-is-it-just-an-old-wives-tale/), has lots of references too...

Comment: See also [Why were both the sun and the moon red today?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/why-were-both-the-sun-and-the-moon-red-today)... isn't not actually quite the same question/topic, but may be of interest